# Mysql query, PHP counting

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following structure of a MySQL first table:

http://www.clubmadam.com/zadatak.jpg

Structure of a MySQL second table:

http://www.clubmadam.com/country.jpg

I need an SQL query to count number of cities in each country and
summarise population for all cities in country;

This is what I have so far:

```
$upit = "SELECT";
$rezultat = mysql_query($upit);
{
}
```

Can a MySQL handle this, or do I need to also use PHP? How would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

This really is SQL 101 stuff, I suggest you do a lot of reading

```
SELECT CountryCode,
       COUNT(Name) as Cities,
       SUM(Population) as Population
  FROM <tablename>
 GROUP BY CountryCode
```

Comment: I think he wanted a count by Country Code (`# cities in ESP, # cities in UKR` etc.)  `GROUP BY Name` will give him duplicated name values.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, this query will give a count of cities based on country:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS CityCount, CountryCode, SUM(Population) AS CountryPopulation
FROM myTableName
GROUP BY CountryCode
```

Per your comment, here is how you can do it across multiple tables:

```
SELECT City.COUNT(*) AS CityCount, Country.LocalName, City.SUM(Population) AS CountryPopulation
FROM City, Country
GROUP BY City.CountryCode
```

Comment: Txank mate this works like charm, can you help me a little more, i have just one table that i have JOIN to get all the results. 
 [link]http://www.clubmadam.com/country.jpg 
The first table is CITY and second table is COUNTRY, i need when some ask city name, Has to have how many cities in that country, and population by all cities, txanks in advance

Comment: I updated the answer.  It should work but if you have problems you can ask.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple MySQL aggregation job using the `SUM()` and `COUNT()` [aggregate funcions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html):

```
$sql = 'SELECT 
  CountryCode, 
  COUNT(ID) as numCities, 
  SUM(Population) as totalPopulation 
  FROM Cities 
  GROUP BY CountryCode';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$upit = "SELECT COUNT(ID) AS cities, SUM(Population) AS population, ContryCode FROM table GROUP BY CountryCode";
$result = mysql_query($upit);
while ($data = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
    // $data->cities is the number of cities and $data->population the sum of people and $data->CountryCode the country code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Count number of cities in Country-code**

```
$upit = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CountryCode) FROM table_name
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($upit);
echo "$num_rows Rows\n";
```

**Summarize population for all cities in Country-code**

Refer @Mark Baker Answer